# How to integrate beta distribution in Python

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, beta-distribution

In R, the following is used to calculate the integral between points 0 and 0.5 on beta distribution with the parameters 10 and 20:

```
 integrate(function(p) dbeta(p,10,20),0,0.5)
```

The result is:

```
0.9692858 absolute error < 6.6e-08
```

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: `scipy.stats.beta(10,20).cdf(0.5)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks for the answer. It seems though cdf takes only one argument (upper limit of the integral).  It throws an error if i want to integrate over 0.2 to 0.5 like this scipy.stats.beta(10,20).cdf(0.2, 0.5).  Also, please answer the question so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `.cdf` attribute of `scipy.stats.beta`. For a proper interval use the difference, e.g.

```
betacdf = scipy.stats.beta(10,20).cdf
betacdf(0.5)-betacdf(0.2)
# 0.9200223098258666
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def f(x): return beta.pdf(x, 10, 20)
res, err = quad(f, 0, 0.5)
print (res)
print (err)
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32204606)